# Opening tag or Utl link using ctrl-]

Tags: vim

I'd like to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to attempt it's default behavior (ie., jump to a tag if possible), but if that fails to try opening a link using the Utl plugin.  My fingers are too hard-wired into trying <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to jump that creating a different mapping isn't working out very well.  I'm no good at VimL, but this is what I'd like to achieve in pseudo-code:

```
function TryJump()
  try
    normal ctrl-]
  catch
    normal Utl
  endtry
endfunction
noremap <c-]> :call TryJump()<cr>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used utl, but assuming you just want it to do `:Utl`, this should work:

```
function! TryJump()
  try
    execute "normal! \<c-]>"
  catch
    Utl
  endtry
endfunction
nnoremap <c-]> :call TryJump()<cr>
```